# Joi schema validation error about a need to require an optional field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema, joi

I am trying to validate value by `Joi.validate` along with `Joi schema`.

This is the schema:

```
let obj = {};

for (let i=1; i<=9; i++) {
  obj[i] = {
    title: Joi.string().min(0).max(16),
    modules: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().min(0).max(100))
  };
}

module.exports = Joi.object().keys(obj);
```

And this is the validation:

```
let schema = require('../permissions-model');
Joi.validate(req.body.permissions, schema, (err, value) => {
  console.log(err);
  if (err) return cast.error(err);
  return cast.ok();
});
```

And this is the error:

```
{ ValidationError: child "7" fails because [child "title" fails because ["title" is not allowed to be empty]]
    at Object.exports.process (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/joi/lib/errors.js:196:19)
    at internals.Object._validateWithOptions (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/joi/lib/types/any/index.js:675:31)
    at module.exports.internals.Any.root.validate (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/joi/lib/index.js:138:23)
    at joi_validate (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/resources/permissions/api/v1-update.js:28:9)
    at module.exports (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/resources/permissions/api/v1-update.js:35:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at /Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/app/middlewares/permission.js:23:14
    at /Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/lib/collection.js:50:5
    at runInAsyncScope (/Users/razbuchnik/Projects/taxi4you/server/node_modules/mongojs/lib/cursor.js:198:5)
  isJoi: true,
  name: 'ValidationError',
  details: 
   [ { message: '"title" is not allowed to be empty',
       path: [Array],
       type: 'any.empty',
       context: [Object] } ],
  _object: 
   { '1': { title: 'בעלים', modules: [Array] },
     '2': { title: 'סדרן ראשי', modules: [Array] },
     '3': { title: 'סדרן' },
     '4': { title: 'נהג' },
     '5': { title: 'קב׳׳ט' },
     '6': { title: 'מזכירה' },
     '7': { title: '' },
     '8': { modules: [Array] },
     '9': { title: '' },
     _id: '5b9df16d58dd3c2e032b768e' },
  annotate: [Function] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.allow('')` to `string()` type if you want to allow empty string.
`string()` type is now allow empty string by default.

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const nowAllowEmptyString = Joi.object().keys({
  title: Joi.string().max(16),
});
const {error: error1} = Joi.validate({title: ''}, nowAllowEmptyString);
console.log(error1); // child "title" fails because ["title" is not allowed to be empty]


const allowEmptyString = Joi.object().keys({
  title: Joi.string().max(16).allow(''),
});
const {error: error2} = Joi.validate({title: ''}, allowEmptyString);
console.log(error2); // null
```

check https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/482